# force ambiguous instance with phantom type

Tags: haskell

I'm using `mysql-simple` and I'm trying to use phantom type to avoid to have to use explicit type signature.

Let's say I'm trying to execute the following query `SELECT firstname, lastname FROM users`.

I would try something like this :

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Database.MySQL.Simple

myQuery :: Query
myQuery = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM users"

main = do
    conn <-connect defaultConnectInfo
    rows <- queryT conn myQuery
    mapM_ print rows
```

This doesn't work because the compiler can't deduce the type of `rows`. The solution is to add a type signature like this :

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Database.MySQL.Simple

myQuery :: Query
myQuery = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM users"

main = do
    conn <-connect defaultConnectInfo
    rows <- queryT conn myQuery
    mapM_ print (rows :: [(String, String)]) ------<< Here
```

The compiler deduces that each row is `(String, String)` and everythign works fine.
This solution is however not satisfying because if I modify `myQuery` I need to modify the `rows` type signature. Moreover, this is a simpified example. In the real code , the query comes from a query combinator (which hold the row type), so there is no way to hardcode the row type.

I tried using a **typed** query using a phantom type

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Database.MySQL.Simple


data QueryT a = QueryT Query  ---------------<< Phantom type
queryT :: Connection -> QueryT a -> IO [a]
queryT conn (QueryT q) = query_ conn q


myQuery :: QueryT (String, String) ----------<< Query holding it's row type
myQuery = QueryT $ "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM users"

main = do
    conn <-connect defaultConnectInfo
    rows <- queryT conn myQuery
    mapM_ print rows
```

This doesn't work. I got the following message :

```
stack.hs:7:26:
No instance for (Database.MySQL.Simple.QueryResults.QueryResults a)
  arising from a use of `query_'
Possible fix:
  add (Database.MySQL.Simple.QueryResults.QueryResults
         a) to the context of
    the type signature for queryT :: Connection -> QueryT a -> IO [a]
In the expression: query_ conn q
In an equation for `queryT': queryT conn (QueryT q) = query_ conn q
```

If I replace the phantom type by `(String, String)` in `queryT` type signature

```
queryT :: Connection -> QueryT a -> IO [(String, String)]
```

Things work again. So what is the difference ?
Why the type inference can't infere that rows is of type `[(String, String)]` ?

(I've tried functional dependencies and type families but that doesn't seem to help either).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't with inferring `(String, String)` for the row type where you *call* `queryT`; that gets inferred just fine.

The issue is in compiling `queryT` itself; that's polymorphic in `a` so the compiler isn't *supposed* to infer `(String, String)`, it's supposed to compile code that will work for *any* type `a`. But `queryT` gets its result by calling `query_`, and `query_` isn't able to work for any type at all, only for the types in the `QueryResult` type class.

But you don't want to be able to run `queryT` on queries that claim to produce `Either (IO [a -> Int]) (Maybe Void)` as the row type any more than `query_` wants that as a possible row type, so the solution is to limit `queryT` to operate on queries whose phantom type is in `QueryResult` too:

```
queryT :: QueryResult a => Connection -> QueryT a -> IO [a]
```

That's exactly what was meant by the suggested "possible fix" of adding `QueryResult a` to the context of `queryT`. The "context" of a type signature is everything before the `=>`, where you write constraints on the type variables involved.

Comment: I didn't read the error message properly indeed. thank you very much.